# SonarQube Run Code Analysis Azure DevOps task fails due not able to locate xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter.dll

Tags: c#, azure-devops, sonarqube

**which versions are you using?** (SonarQube, Scanner, Plugin, and any relevant extension)

Task version 4 - Azure DevOps Services

**what are you trying to achieve?**

Run Code Analysis

**what have you tried so far to achieve this?**

1. Stop and Start the agent services
2. Delete the folder _work and trigger a new run
3. Install a new agent
4. Run the agent with the local account
5. Use a different version of dotnet task
6. Add and Sleep task for 20 sec to avoid other resources using the
   same file
7. Using the SonarQube Run Code Analysis Pluging instead the CMD call
   execution
8. Using the SonarQube *Run Code Analysis* Pluging instead the *CMD*
   call execution in ver *5
9. Fixed JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME
10. Updating VS2019

***Error Log:**

17:56:22.652 17:56:22.652 WARNING: File ‘C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.test.sdk\16.6.1\build\netcoreapp2.1\Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk.Program.cs’ is not located under the root directory ‘F:\AzureServicesAgents\AgentU07_work\1\s’ and will not be analyzed.
17:56:22.652 17:56:22.652 WARNING: File ‘C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile.nuget\packages\microsoft.testplatform.testhost\16.6.1\build\netcoreapp2.1\x64\testhost.exe’ is not located under the root directory ‘F:\AzureServicesAgents\AgentU07_work\1\s’ and will not be analyzed.
17:56:22.653 17:56:22.653 WARNING: File ‘C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile.nuget\packages\microsoft.testplatform.testhost\16.6.1\build\netcoreapp2.1\x64\testhost.dll’ is not located under the root directory ‘F:\AzureServicesAgents\AgentU07_work\1\s’ and will not be analyzed.
17:56:22.653 17:56:22.653 WARNING: File

***I have check and this file is present on above path***
‘C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile.nuget\packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio\2.4.1\build\netcoreapp1.0\xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter.dll’ is not located under the root directory

***I have check and this file is present on above path***
‘F:\AzureServicesAgents\AgentU07_work\1\s’ and will not be analyzed.
17:56:22.653 17:56:22.653 WARNING: File ‘C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile.nuget\packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio\2.4.1\build\netcoreapp1.0\xunit.runner.reporters.netcoreapp10.dll’ is not located under the root directory ‘F:\AzureServicesAgents\AgentU07_work\1\s’ and will not be analyzed.
17:56:22.653 17:56:22.653 WARNING: File ‘C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile.nuget\packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio\2.4.1\build\netcoreapp1.0\xunit.runner.utility.netcoreapp10.dll’ is not located under the root directory ‘F:\AzureServicesAgents\AgentU07_work\1\s’ and will not be analyzed.
Calling the TFS Processor executable…

Comment: What is the problem here? What you posted are warnings that some DLLs seem (rightfully) not to be a part of your project, hence not being analyzed. None of these warnings should be fatal.

Comment: Hello @orhtej2 nice to meet you, I'm a complete beginner with SonarQube, with that being said there are two situations presented with this Pipeline #1 Warning, related to the *.dll* not been analyzed, after reading carefully your comment did notice you're right the Pipeline Highlights this in Ambar as [Warning]. #2 Post-processing failed.  Exit code:1. ##[error]The process 'F:\AzureServicesAgents\AgentU07\_work\_tasks\SonarQubePrepare_15b84ca1-b62f-4a2a-a403-89b77a063157\4.24.0\classic-sonar-scanner-msbuild\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: Run Code Analysis

Comment: @orhtej2, If I navigate to this long path associated with the VSTS_Agent working folder I can see that the * SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe* is present in there, therefore no idea from my end why complaints?

Comment: SOLVED, this was solved by:
1) changing to the **version 4** of the **SonarQube Task**
2) Installing the **Universal Windows Platform** package on Visual Studio 2019 located in our Build Server/VM

Comment: Never add "Solved" or similar to the title.

Comment: Hello @jps, how can I close this thread/question? thanks in advance

Comment: On Stackoverflow, "Closed" means that there are problems with the question (e.g. unclear, off-topic, not reproducible etc.)  and no one should answer the question until the problems are fixed or the question might get deleted when the problems don't get fixed after a while. But usually questions just remain open and even if the asker found a solution, other people can add their answers/solutions. There are questions with dozens of answers. If you find it worthwhile and helpful for other people, you can add an answer with your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading several dependencies logs, did find out that in reality those files were analyze, it seems that "Azure DevOps" and "SonarQube" can't agree on what did happen after this pipeline execution so the take out is:

- Depending on how it was implemented your SonarQube read the logs regarding the execution you are having issues with.
- Compare those logs against the one from the VSTS_agent log associate with the specific task that throws the error and check the time stamp to ensure if there was an actual error or the execution passed clean

Two other engineers with me agreed this is an error of data interpretation across the pipeline but, the logs prove that they passed, and the report was created in the SonarQube endpoint, so it would be ignored